# (void method type vs method that returns) for altering a private global variable

Tags: java, c#, c++, oop

Let's say we have a global variable called x, as shown below:

```
public class test
{
    private int x = 0;
    //lots of code here...
}
```

Now lets say we want, at some arbitrary point, to alter the value of x within the  class test (not from outside the class).

There are two ways to do  this:

**Using a void method:**

```
public class test
{
     private int x = 0;
     //lots of code here...
     changeX();

     private void changeX()
     {
         // calculate stuff
         this.x = newXValue;
     }
}
```

**Using a int type method:**

```
public class test
{
     private int x = 0;
     //lots of code here...
     x = changeX();

     private int changeX()
     {
         // calculate stuff
         return = newXValue;
     }
}
```

Is there any reason as to why I should choose one over the other? Security reasons? readability?

I have this happening throughout my program and am having trouble deciding on which convention to use.

Comment: The code that you've shown isn't valid in any of the languages that you've tagged the question with.  So, which is better, neither, as neither compiles.

Comment: None of your examples will compile in C#.

Comment: This *isn't* a language-agnostic question - and the environment affects a good bit if it's 'proper' to do.

Comment: This is a logic question that pertains to the listed languages, more than a code specific question.

Comment: You provided some code as if there was some "main" code executing in the body of the class. That is not the case. Running this "main" code in a method would defeat the purpose of the question I believe, as it would be run in a void method itself, calling in turn another method. Please clarify what you want by provided compiling code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your code remains private to the class, I see no reason there would be security issues.  I personally would chose the void version of the method, since anyone calling the changeX() method also has access to x directly (there all in the same class).  Returning int opens up the possibility of a local variable having operations performed on it that should be performed on the class variable.

Comment: What makes you think it *"should [always] be performed on the class variable"*?

Answer (score 1):

If we clearly are talking about private stuff here (private method and private field), then I almost always prefer the functional version of the method: returning the value.

If you can encapsulate all calculations in the body of this method, then I see no reason to force it to update the private field as well. The methods should do one thing, and do it well. Just calculate and return the value, and let the calling code somewhere else in your class do whatever it likes with it, because that code will know the general picture.

However, you would obviously change the name of method to something like `calculateY()`, where Y would *not* refer the name of your field, but rather the data that it holds (the field X would be named describing how it is useful to the class, while Y would describe how it is calculated, which may or may not be 2 different things depending on the use case).

Comment: But it's *not* a "functional" version due to a side-effect; doesn't matter what it is named. Some languages (and ecosystems around such) are a strict modify/read split while others encourage a modify+return ..

Comment: @user2864740 There is no side-effect in the method, it simply calculates and returns a value. The caller then assigns that value to the field or not, but that's up to the caller, it is not a side effect of calling the method. Maybe I wasn't clear in my sentence, I guess I clarified now.

Comment: @user2864740 Regarding the second part of your comment, I think it depends more on the precise use case and calculations than on the language/ecosystem. I could be Java or C, I would still find that decoupling the calculation from what you do with it is best (I have to precise here that we are talking about a **private** method, this could not be generalized to public methods).